allow user to install software not by apt-get but via "Ubuntu software"
Please I try to find a solution to be able to allow a user, ex: caisse, to be able to install any software he want via the desktop ubuntu 22.04 and software UI called "Ubuntu software" without to have to be asked administrator password. ?
I have tested many solutions like Polkit or 'visudo' tricks without any success.
Could there be a way without to give administrative rights to caisse ?
Cheers,
